# Input array of unique values from given range

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I'm filling in an array of values with user input. Code I have does most of it but I want to show explicit message if user input is rejected (range/uniquenss check) before asking for it again.

In particular

1. I want to display error message when a user inputs an int value less than 1 or greater than 25 to one array.
2. I want to display error message if the user has already entered the same value as before.

The code I have just repeatedly ask for the same row till acceptable value provided:

```
int[] vektor = new int[4];

//take input from user
for (int i = 0; i < vektor.Length; i++)
{
    // as long as value not beetween 1 or 25
    while (!(vektor[i] >= 1 && vektor[i] <= 25))
    {
        // Entry row number
        int x = i + 1;
        //ready input and store in array called vektor
        Console.Write("row number:{0}: Enter one integer:", x);
        vektor[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }    
}
```

I understand that I need to add something like following `if` but I'm not sure where to fit it.

```
if (userInput <= 0 || userInput => 26)
{
   Console.WriteLine("You entered wrong value, try again")
}
```

as well as some form of `vektor.Contains(?)` to check for presence of the input in the array.

At the end I need to achieve something like

```
row 1: -3
You entered wrong value, try again
row 1: 10
row 2: 10
You entered dupicate value, try again
row 2: 5
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one `while loop`. Just do not `increase` counter if the input is wrong

```
using System;
namespace learn_c_
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] vektor = new int[4];
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < vektor.Length)
            {
                Console.Write("row number:{0}: Enter one integer: ", counter + 1);
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                // Note that only part of array is "filled" so limiting search 
                // to only items we already filled out
                int indexOfNum = Array.IndexOf(vektor, number, 0, counter);
                // [Range] check
                if (number < 1 || number > 25)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered wrong value, try again");
                    continue;
                }
                //[Duplicate] value check
                else if (indexOfNum != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered duplicate value as {0}, try again", vektor[indexOfNum]);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    vektor[counter++] = number;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that while using `Enumerable.Contains` on an array is an option it will search whole array. For arrays it is easier to use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_System_Int32_System_Int32_) especially since it let you specify what part of the array to search. That is important part of the exercise here as only part of array (up to `counter` in this case) is "filled" with values, the rest have default value of 0.

Comment: oh yeah! Oversight! let me add!

Comment: Note that the other answer got it *looking wrong* already. Race to the correct one :) that also looks correct.

Comment: Your "contains" is as wrong *looking* as the other answer :(  I guess noone can believe that array has values before you put them into array... Indeed code works for numbers selected here... but it is just setting up OP for failure - which they seem to be perfectly ok with...

Comment: Some side question. Is there any good open-source project I should learn for Micro Service and architecture in c#.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: oh sh** now i become 2nd.. :(

Comment: I don't have good suggestion on reading about microservices...

Comment: Oh! I checked the other solution. there is nothing like `Contains` for array. how that will work?

Comment: I've edited the answer with comment about Contains... and fixed you search too.

Comment: Yeah! saw ur comment. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
//create one array named vektor with 4 zero values.
int[] vektor = new int[4]; 

//take input from user
for (int i = 0; i < vektor.Length; i++)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    var numberInValid = true;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("row number:{0}: Enter one integer:", i + 1);
        userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // as long as value not beetween 1 or 25
        if (userInput < 1 || userInput > 25)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered wrong value, try again");
        }

        //Check if user has already entered them same value before
        // NOTE that initialized arrays has all 0, but we do not allow 
        // 0 in above checks, so scanning whole array is fine in this case
        // if 0 allowed you need to scan only first "filled" part of the array.
        else if (vektor.Contains(userInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number already entered, try again");
        }
        else
        {
            numberInValid = false;
        }
    }
    while (numberInValid);
    vektor[i] = userInput;
}
```

Comment: I don't get your comment! There is no infinite loop, take a good look, it has a break condition

Comment: Sorry - you have do-whole... Explaining what you do is good idea... At very least you should explain why `Contains` actually is enough *in this particular case*... (which clearly looks wrong as code checks for all values in array rather the once already entered)

Comment: Also not the you did not answer the question - "i want something like this if i on entry number 2 enter 29 as value." - your code is essentially identical to OPs one as it simply repeatedly asks for "row:1" rather than asking to retry the same row...

Comment: The question clearly states that there shouldn't be repeat values in the array, hence checking if it is already there using `Contains`. Have a good look at the question

Comment: I mean... `(new int [4]).Contains(0)` is false only on February 30...

Comment: I totally get the answer... I'm just saying that it *looks* wrong but actually produces correct result... (and does not show "You entered wrong value, try again" text which I think OP is actually asking about).

Comment: Thanks for putting good explanation why Contains on whole array actually works here :)

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation.